# React: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, sanity

I am building a blog with React and Sanity everything so far went pretty good but now when i am trying to add SinglePost pages for each blog the code was fine but when i went to a post and clicked i got redirected to SinglePost page and got this error.

**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

Check the render method of `SinglePost`.
▶ 22 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/components/SinglePost.js:31

[Error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfEF4.jpg)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfEF4.jpg

My Single Post Component looks like this

```
import React , { useState, useEffect }from "react";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import sanityClient from "../client.js"
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";
import { BlockContent } from "@sanity/block-content-to-react"

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(sanityClient);
function urlFor(source) {
    return builder.image(source)
}
export default function SinglePost() {
    const [singlePost, setSinglePost] = useState(null);
    const { slug } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        sanityClient.fetch(`*[slug.current == "${slug}"] {
            title,
            _id,
            slug,
            mainImage{
                asset->{
                    _id,
                    url
                }
            },
            body,
            "name": author->name,
            "authorImage": author->image
        }`)
        .then((data) => setSinglePost(data[0]))
        .catch(console.error);
    }, [slug]);

    if (!singlePost) return <div>Loading....</div>
    
    return (
        <main className="bg-gray-200 min-h-screen p-12">
            <article className="container shadow-lg mx-auto bg-green-100 rounded-lg">
                <header className="relative">
                    <div className="absolute h-full w-full flex items-center justify-center p-8">
                        <div className="bg-white bg-opacity-75 rounded p-12">
                            <h1 className="cursive text-3xl lg:text-6xl mb-4">
                                {singlePost.title}
                            </h1>
                            <div className="flex justify-center text-gray-800">
                                <img src={urlFor(singlePost.authorImage).url()} 
                                alt={singlePost.name}
                                className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full"
                                />
                                <p className="cursive flex items-center pl-2 text-2xl">
                                    {singlePost.name}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src={singlePost.mainImage.asset.url}
                    alt={singlePost.title}
                    className="w-full object-cover rounded-t"
                    style={{height: "400px"}}
                    />
                </header>
                <div className="px-16 lg:px-48 py-12 lg:py-20 prose lg:prose-xl max-w-full">
                    <BlockContent blocks={singlePost.body} projectId="abmvfbq5" dataset="production"/>
                    </div>
            </article>
        </main>
    )
}
```

I dont find anything wrong with the code right now, can anyone help me by looking at the error and tell me what is wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: I would check what's in `data` and in `data[0]`, maybe something is undefined there?

Answer (score 0):

I see two things in the code that hint towards an issue. Without seeing your `client.js` it is difficult to tell.

```
   useEffect(() => {
// string interpolation for ${slug} needs to be surrounded by ticks and not double string quotations
        sanityClient.fetch(`*[slug.current == "${slug}"] {
            title,
            _id,
            slug,
            mainImage{
                asset->{
                    _id,
                    url
                }
            },
            body,
            "name": author->name,
            "authorImage": author->image
        }`) <----- did you mean to send an entire function as an argument?
        .then((data) => setSinglePost(data[0]))
        .catch(console.error);
    }, [slug]);
```